# Get reference code with deeplink url through app store

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, deep-linking

I have some functionality in my app. If user clicks on referral link from outside of the app(from messages,whatsapp etc), it will navigating to app and I am making register url with reference code. After that I am navigating to register screen and loading that register url in web view and it displaying referral code in required field.(this is all happening if our app installed in iPhone device)

But what I need is when app is not installed and we click on referral link-
If app is not installed then it should redirect to appstore and once the app is installed it should redirect to register screen with referral code in it.

```
-(void)handelReferral:(NSString *)strReferral{

if ([[SuperClass sharedSingletonSuperClass] checkifStringNotNull:strReferral]) {
    NSString *strReferralCode;
    if ([strReferral rangeOfString:@"ref/"].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSURLComponents *urlComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strReferral]
                                                    resolvingAgainstBaseURL:NO];
        NSArray *queryItems = urlComponents.queryItems;
        
        if (queryItems.count > 0) {
            NSString *queryValue = [self valueForKey:@"al" fromQueryItems:queryItems];
            strReferralCode = [queryValue lastPathComponent];
        } else {
            strReferralCode = strReferral.lastPathComponent;
        }

        NSString *strRegisterUrl = [ConfigurationManager shared].data.strRegisterUrl;
        
        NSString *finalRefUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?utm_campaign=app_refferal_ref/ref/%@&utm_medium=app&utm_source=app_refferal",strRegisterUrl,strReferralCode];

        if ([self.ReferralDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(userClickedOnReferralDelegate)]) {
            [self.ReferralDelegate userClickedOnReferralDelegate];
        } else {
            if ([[SuperClass sharedSingletonSuperClass]isPhoneNumberIsAvailable] == false) {
                NSLog(@"finalRefUrl=====%@",finalRefUrl);
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isComingFromRef"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:finalRefUrl forKey:@"finalRefUrl"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                [ServiceGeneralNotifications sharedSingleton].isUserTryingToLogin = YES;
                [[SuperClass sharedSingletonSuperClass] pushToLoginScreen];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler {

[self callServiceToPostCampaignDataWithURL:userActivity.webpageURL];
if ([[SuperClass sharedSingletonSuperClass]checkifStringNotNull:[userActivity.webpageURL absoluteString]]) {
    [self handelReferral:[userActivity.webpageURL absoluteString]];
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Firebase Dynamic links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/)

> With Dynamic Links, your users get the best available experience for the platform they open your link on. If a user opens a Dynamic Link on iOS or Android, they can be taken directly to the linked content in your native app. If a user opens the same Dynamic Link in a desktop browser, they can be taken to the equivalent content on your website.

> In addition, Dynamic Links work across app installs: if a user opens a Dynamic Link on iOS or Android and doesn't have your app installed, the user can be prompted to install it; then, after installation, your app starts and can access the link.

Comment: Thank you for answer.But I think it will work when we invite and receive from firebase dynamic link only.Currently we create referral link from server only.

Comment: @VijayKumar You can do this with firebase [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest)